# Real name of protagonist in Banshee?

Tags: character, banshee

In Banshee the protagonist takes over the name of the Sheriff **Lucas Hood**.
I just watched the last episode and wondered if his **real name** was ever revealed?

I added this picture ([source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2017109/board/thread/257459747?p=4&d=257479133#257479133)) of the FBI file, but you cannot read the name - and I am not sure if this would be his real name anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's John Smith but it's not known if it's his real name or just another alias

Here are a few comments about the subject from reddit

[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Banshee/comments/2tqm36/about_lucas_hood_real_name/co1heun)

> In the latest episode during the questioning, we see him say that his name is John Smith, but that is probably not his real name.

[2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Banshee/comments/20s637/lucas_hood_spoilers/cg6qozp)

> He does tell the other person across the table from him in Season 2 Origins that his name is John Smith. What if at the very end of the show, we find out it really was his real name and he wasn't just messing with them

Also in the character's [wikia page](http://banshee.wikia.com/wiki/Lucas_Hood) you can find the name John Smith under "Also known as"

Comment: but isn't John Smith a common name? which constantly uses to cover up real name in plain sight or something?

Answer (score 2):

It's John Walton from what I can tell.  First name definitely John, last name looks like Walton.

Comment: If you watch the show and freeze frame it as he is opening file there is an angle at which you can read it somewhat

Comment: Can you provide that screenshot or something? Or some source to your claim.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the image I see says John Walton.  The strand is too long to be Smith, and I think the writers are having a gag on us all by using 'John Boy's' name from the squeaky clean 'Waltons' series.

Answer (score 0):

It's John smith at the top of page but it does mention Walton further down page, maybe someone will get a clearer image?